# Повторно получить данные через HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net

Пишу информер на vb.net 2005. Задача парсить страницу через определенные промежутки времени и проверять её на наличие новой строки. Создаю HttpWebRequest, получаю ответ, проверяю условие - все отлично работает, но как только пытаюсь повторить(через минуту примерно) прога виснет и выдает, что превышено время ожидания от сервера. Что может быть не так? Могу ли я как-то удалить старый запрос?

Comment: Возможно, не очищены ресурсы после первого запроса.

Comment: А как это сделать правильно?

Comment: А, всё решилось, просто response надо зарывать сразу после обработки из него инфы(до следующего response)